# How to create a "shiny" effect like this using CSS gradients?

Tags: html, css, gradient

Is it possible to create the following using CSS only?

[image]

I have created the container and the rounded corners. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/UxSdU/).

But I don't know how to get the slight shiny effect. Is it possible to do this in CSS? If so how?

Below is the code I have written so far.

**HTML**

```
<div id="phone-outer">
    <div id="phone-inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#phone-outer {
    margin-bottom:200px;
    margin:0 auto;  
    width:400px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#333;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
}

#phone-inner {
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:360px;
    height:460px;   
}
```

Comment: I'm not good enough with gradients to answer properly, but you might want to try a large radial gradient, using rgba colours to create the semi-transparent white shade, that's re-positioned so that most of it is behind the white area.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try. I'm okay with basic CSS but gradients has always been a tough spot for me too.

Comment: and for some inspiration! http://tjrus.com/iphone :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Close enough I hope:

http://jsfiddle.net/UxSdU/13/

```
#phone-outer {    
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;

    box-shadow: 0 3px 0.7px 1px #777777, 0 -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;

    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;


    background-image: linear-gradient(right, #111 11%, #333 56%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #111 11%, #333 56%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #111 11%, #333 56%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #111 11%, #333 56%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #111 11%, #333 56%);
    background-image: gradient(right, #111 11%, #333 56%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great! I did a little bit of tweaking like removing this line `border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;` and adjusting the `box-shadow` values. It looks fine now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for the subtle gradient glow, something like this should do it:

```
background:#222 -webkit-radial-gradient(20% 80%, 60% 60%, rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,0));
```

This is for webkit, you can apply the -moz and -o equivalents depending on your support table.

You can also add multiple box shadows to create the black shadow as well, something like:

```
box-shadow:0px 2px .7px 1px #777, inset 0 -7px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/opinaj/4

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. :) This works well but only in Chrome. I tried adding the `background:#222 -webkit-radial-gradient(20% 80%, 60% 60%, rgba(255,255,255,.15), rgba(255,255,255,0));` line prefixed with `-moz-` and `-o` but they didn't work in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: @Isuru FF and Opera have different gradient syntax, you can read up on  some of it here (just google yourself to the rest): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Box-Shadow property,

```
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #666;
```

Updated Fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UxSdU/2/

UPDATE:

For that you can use border:

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UxSdU/6/

Comment: You actually answered another question. +1 I was wondering how to get that thin border too. :D But what I want here is that slight shine on the bottom section. Can you see? To the left side.

Comment: No. Not the border. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/YjBz1AM.jpg) image. I hope its noticeable. Its really hard to see. In some screen resolutions.

Comment: @Isuru: if I have interpreted the issue correctly. the answer is again box-shadow. Just play around with box shadow values. I guess probably you might need to slightly tweak the layout too...

Answer (score 0):

Play around with this a little http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and you may be able to figure something out. A background image would be much easier though. Any reason why you can't just use that image?

Comment: I have a few form controls that goes inside the white area. If I use an image, when the browser resizes, the image would move when the controls are in one place. This is for a horizontal layout. Went through a lot of trouble with the similar approach earlier. Plus this site has a lot of big images in it already. Im trying to keep the usage of images to a minimum to squeeze out some performance.